# Does there exist a polynomial $P$ such that $|P(x) − \cos x| \le10^{-6}$ for all (real) x?

Tags: polynomials

Does there exist a polynomial $P$ such that $|P(x) − \cos x| \le10^{-6}$ for all (real) x?

I am struggling to understand how to even start with this question, as it is not clear to me what this really means. Obviously $-1\le \cos x\le 1$, so maybe there is a way to use that, or maybe use the small angle approximations?

I am really not too sure, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible because any polynomial is unbounded over the reals and so this quantity is also unbounded.

Answer (score 6):

The polynomial has to be positive at even multiples of $\pi$ where the cosine is $+1$, negative at odd multiples of $\pi$ where the cosine is $-1$. Therefore infinitely many zeroes.  And we're having a bad day.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the fact that $\cos x$ is bounded implies that it can't be approximated by any polynomial $P(x)$. Consider the largest power of $x$ involved in the polynomial. For $x$ sufficiently large, this term will be much bigger than all others combined, so if this term has a positive coefficient $P(x)$ will be large and positive for $x$ sufficiently large, and if it has a negative coefficient then $P(x)$ will be large and negative.

Comment: Is the condition satisfied for all real values of $x$? This does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: @sammygerbil I don't understand your comment. We can't have a polynomial satisfying $-2<P(x)<2$ for all real values of $x$, so the stronger condition asked for certainly can't be satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

On any finite interval that would be possible but every non-constant polynomial $P(x)$ diverges to $\pm{\infty}$ as x goes to $\pm{\infty}$ making it impossible.